# iOS - Re-Attempt Failed NSURLRequests In NSURLSession

Tags: ios, api, authentication, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

In my app, 2-4 API calls to my server can be happening at the same time (asynchronously) within my API class's `NSURLSession`. In order to make API requests to my server, I must supply the authentication token in the `HTTPHeaderField` of each `NSURLRequest`. The token is valid for one day, and if it becomes invalid after one day, I need to refresh the token.

I do this in the following code in my API class:

```
/*!
 * @brief sends a request as an NSHTTPURLResponse. This method is private.
 * @param request The request to send.
 * @param success A block to be called if the request is successful.
 * @param error A block to be called if the request fails.
 */
-(void)sendTask:(NSURLRequest*)request successCallback:(void (^)(NSDictionary*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))errorCallback
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        [self parseResponse:response data:data fromRequest:request successCallback:success errorCallback:^(NSString *error)
        {
            //if auth token expired and getting "not authenticated" error (status 401)
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 401) {
                [self refreshAuthenticationTokenWithSuccessCallback:^(NSDictionary *response) {
                    self.authToken = response[@"token"];
                    //attempt to re-try the request that failed due to token expiration
                    [self sendTask:request successCallback:success errorCallback:errorCallback];
                } errorCallback:^(NSString *error) {
                    //two weeks have passed and the token is no longer refreshable
                    NSLog(@"TOKEN NOT REFRESHABLE! HAVE TO LOG IN MANUALLY");
                }];
            }
        }];
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

This `sendTask` method gets executed with every API request I make in the app, so I just realized this is a bad way of doing it. If 3 API requests fail due to the token being invalid (one day passed), then all 3 of these API requests are going to attempt to make the API call to refresh the authentication token.

Is there a way for me to, in case ONE of the API requests fail, refresh the authentication token only ONCE and then re-attempt the failed API calls?

***EDIT***

I edited the title of the question to indicate that I'm working with NSURLSession

***PROGRESS***

So far, to prevent several failed API requests from trying to refresh the authentication token at the same time, I have an `NSArray` for all the failed requests and an `NSNumber` that serves as a lock to make sure that the authentication token is only trying to be refreshed once. I do this in the following code:

```
-(void)sendTask:(NSURLRequest*)request successCallback:(void (^)(NSDictionary*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))errorCallback
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        MyAPIInterface *__weak weakSelf = self;
        [self parseResponse:response data:data fromRequest:request successCallback:success errorCallback:^(NSString *error)
        {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 401) {
                if ([error isEqualToString:@"invalid_credentials"]) {
                    errorCallback(@"Invalid username and/or password");
                }
                else if ([error isEqualToString:@"Unknown error"]) {
                    errorCallback(error);
                }
                else {
                    if (!weakSelf.alreadyRefreshingToken.boolValue) {

                        //lock alreadyRefreshingToken boolean
                        weakSelf.alreadyRefreshingToken = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
                        NSLog(@"NOT REFRESHING TOKEN");

                        // add failed request to failedRequests array
                        NSMutableArray *mutableFailedRequests = [weakSelf.failedRequests mutableCopy];
                        [mutableFailedRequests addObject:request];
                        weakSelf.failedRequests = [mutableFailedRequests copy];

                        // refresh auth token
                        [weakSelf refreshAuthenticationTokenWithSuccessCallback:^(NSDictionary *response) {

                            //store authToken
                            weakSelf.authToken = response[@"token"];
                            NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                            [defaults setObject:weakSelf.authToken forKey:@"authToken"];
                            [defaults synchronize];

                            //attempt to re-try all requests that failed due to token expiration
                            for (NSURLRequest *failedRequest in weakSelf.failedRequests) {
                                [weakSelf sendTask:failedRequest successCallback:success errorCallback:errorCallback];
                            }

                            //clear failedRequests array and unlock alreadyRefreshingToken boolean
                            [weakSelf clearFailedRequests];
                            weakSelf.alreadyRefreshingToken = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

                            NSLog(@"TOKEN REFRESHING SUCCESSFUL THO");

                        } errorCallback:^(NSString *error) {

                            NSLog(@"TOKEN NOT REFRESHABLE! HAVE TO LOG IN MANUALLY");

                            //clear failedRequests array
                            [weakSelf clearFailedRequests];

                            errorCallback(@"Your login session has expired");

                        }];
                    }
                    else  {
                        NSLog(@"ALREADY REFRESHING TOKEN. JUST ADD TO FAILED LIST");
                        NSMutableArray *mutableFailedRequests = [weakSelf.failedRequests mutableCopy];
                        [mutableFailedRequests addObject:request];
                        weakSelf.failedRequests = [mutableFailedRequests copy];
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"ERROR STRING THO: %@", error);
                errorCallback(error);
            }
        }];
    }];
    [task resume];
}

#pragma mark Custom Methods

-(void)clearFailedRequests {
    NSMutableArray *mutableFailedRequests = [self.failedRequests mutableCopy];
    [mutableFailedRequests removeAllObjects];
    self.failedRequests = [mutableFailedRequests copy];
}
```

Am I going about this correctly? One part that I'm paranoid about is that I'm not really calling the `success` or `error` callback at certain points. Can this lead to problems?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using [self sendTask:], try with [weakSelf sendTask]. Check below code:

```
-(void)sendTask:(NSURLRequest*)request successCallback:(void (^)(NSDictionary*))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString*))errorCallback
{

   __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        [self parseResponse:response data:data fromRequest:request successCallback:success errorCallback:^(NSString *error)
        {
            //if auth token expired and getting "not authenticated" error (status 401)
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*) response;
            if (httpResp.statusCode == 401) {
                [self refreshAuthenticationTokenWithSuccessCallback:^(NSDictionary *response) {
                    self.authToken = response[@"token"];
                    //attempt to re-try the request that failed due to token expiration
                    [weakSelf sendTask:request successCallback:success errorCallback:errorCallback];
                } errorCallback:^(NSString *error) {
                    //two weeks have passed and the token is no longer refreshable
                    NSLog(@"TOKEN NOT REFRESHABLE! HAVE TO LOG IN MANUALLY");
                }];
            }
        }];
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

Comment: Woops, thanks for the catch. I forgot to put the weak self in there. But how is this going to prevent several failed requests from attempting to refresh the token at the same time?

Comment: It won't, but it fixes only retry problem.